# How to map column type string to enum in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Postgres and Spring Data.
Entity looks as follows:

```
public class Market {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

/**
 * aka first currency
 */
@NotNull
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Currency baseCurrency;

/**
 * aka second currency
 */
@NotNull
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Currency quoteCurrency;
...
```

I have the following query in

```
@Query(value = "SELECT BASE_CURRENCY FROM MARKETS UNION SELECT QUOTE_CURRENCY FROM MARKETS", nativeQuery = true)
Set<Currency> findAllSupportedCurrencies();
```

Currency is the enum

```
public enum Currency {
EUR(false),
USD(false),
PLN(false),
BTC(true),
LTC(true),
ETH(true),
```

...

Problem occurs in runtime when I have steps as follows

```
//        When
    Set<Currency> output = marketRepository.findAllSupportedCurrencies();
    for(Currency currency : output){
        System.out.println(currency);
    }
```

I get Cast exception.. Any idea how to proper map string to enum without Currency.valueOf(...) everywhere ?

Comment: It should work without any type of cast or valueOf, could you please try without native query @Query("SELECT DISTINCT m.baseCurrency from Market m") ?

Comment: Yes, this work correctly. But I have to use UNION keyword, and it's not supported by JPQL